# "Circular dependency between plugins" when trying to run Code Analysis in Visual C++

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, code-analysis

I'm trying to run "Code Analysis" for a solution containing a Visual C++ dynamic library project and a Visual C++ console application project. In Visual Studio 2012 I select *BUILD* - *Run Code Analysis on Solution* and the output I see is

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Main, Configuration: Debug-Dll Win32 ------
1>  main.cpp
1>c1xxast : fatal error C1252: Circular dependency between plugins
2>------ Rebuild All started: Project: test, Configuration: Debug-Dll Win32 ------
2>  test.cpp
2>c1xxast : fatal error C1252: Circular dependency between plugins
```

I Googled but it looks like I'm the only person on the planet with this problem.

How do I start resolving this?

Comment: well after 7 months of your wait, I wouldn't say you are all alone :) I am also getting similar error "c1xxast : fatal error C1252: Circular dependency between plugins" after upgrading my project from VS2010 to VS 2013. I am also looking for a solution.

Comment: @nishantcop That's sad.